# adding multiple sessions into one (for permission)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

this is my code and I've set permissions so if a user id is 132 he/she will see button1, etc. The problem is that I have multiple of these permission throughout the webpage (for other functions) and if I need to add someone I have to change it in 5/6 places rather than one. Can I combine all the sessions into one master session? Also I dont want to create a table in the DB

```
    else if (Session["UserId"].Equals("132") || (Session["UserId"].Equals("210"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("41")) || (Session["UserId"].Equals("103"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("404")) || (Session["UserId"].Equals("130"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("92")) || (Session["UserId"].Equals("490"))
                || (Session["UserId"].Equals("172")))
            {
//do something
}
```

Comment: This solution is not scalable and exposes a few vulnerabilities. It sounds like you want role based access control. I.e. a user logs in, your system detects if they are an administrator or a certain role and displays more options accordingly.

Comment: Your authorization is flawed, why not just use claims/policy? If user have a claim for say `can-see-button1` then do something.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a seperate database table for permissions or add another row to the existing user-table with a boolean to check if the user is valid to see the button.

This is really too much just to check if a user is allowed to see the button or not.

You could also create a list with the userids and check if the current logged in user is in the list, then show the button.

*Edit cause of comment to serve some code:*

```
var allowedUserIds = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
var currentUserId = Session["UserId"];
bool isInList = allowedUserIds.IndexOf(currentUserId) != -1;

if(isInList){
...
}
```

Comment: it's not for a button, it's for a more complicate task. I used button as an example

Comment: okay. Just to centralize the userIds i would create a list and just check if the currentUserId is in the list. In my opinion the easiest way.

Comment: can you write the code? Im kinda a nubie to c# asp. Thanks!

Comment: but please, its really better to create scalable code than using some hardcoded stuff like that. After weeks of coding, nobody will know something about a list called allowedUserIds.